# YAML - записать значение

Tags: python, yaml

Добрый вечер.

Как можно записать отдельно значение отдельной переменной, а не всего файла в Python?

Имеется конфиг:

```
str: "1234"
record: 10
x: "test"
```

Мне нужно перезаписать только значение record на число, например 30.

Comment: В самом файле конфига нет переменных, есть только строки. Поэтому, файл проще перезаписать. А вот для работы с самим содержимым в питоне есть модуль https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/configparser.html.

Comment: А можно без перезаписи файла?

Comment: @MrTrojan, "а смысл?" (с) народ ;)